# Jetpack Compose Fill remaining space in Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a Row with max width, I want to place a Icon at start then a text and then another Icon at end.
I have specific sizes of icon and I want the Text to fill up the remaining space.

```kotlin
Row(
   Modifier
   .fillMaxWidth()
   .height(30.dp)
){
  Icon(Modifier.size(20.dp))

  Text() // Fill this with remaining space available

  Icon(Modifier.size(20.dp))
}
```

If I do `fillMaxWidth` in text then Icons goes out of the view.

How to do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can apply `Modifier.weight(1f)` to the `Text` composable.

Something like:

```
Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(30.dp)
){
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"", Modifier.size(20.dp))

    Text("Text",Modifier.weight(1f)) // Fill this with remaining space available

    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"", Modifier.size(20.dp))
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have one more problem. i have decreased the height of TextField but the Placeholder text and input text are getting cropped. i.e. only 50% visible. how to solve it?

Comment: @DelusionaL Try to decrease the textsize

Comment: Then it's getting too small, only 8.sp is working which affects accessibility.